# Angular Cloud Firestore get data based on logged In User

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angular9

I have a firestore which will look like this: 
[Cloud Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abnyV.png)

So in few word I have some users which can log in to my application and create recipe. 
And in 'My recipe' page I will have the list of recipes that a user is having. 
So I have 1 collection 'User' and inside that 1 collection 'Recipes' with multiple recipes.

I have implemented the Firestore Google login and this is working as I get uid. etc...  THis is inside auth.service.ts:

[auth.service.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qiiB.png)

and I want to create a recipes.service.ts with a methode getRecipes() which will getRecipes under users/$(user.uid)/Recipes

anyone can help here? I dont find any tutorial to display data with subcollection.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't share images of code.  You should copy the code into the question itself, and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

For you to retrieve data of collections with nested collection, you can easily return one, by using a code similar to this: `db.collection('users').doc('<user>').collection('Recipes').get()`. Using like this, it will return the document with the subcollection, per user.

However, there is no way of getting the sub-collections together with all the documents at once. But, there is a good workaround available [here](http://www.lukasjakob.com/how-to-get-firestore-collection-data-with-sub-collections-in-angular/), that for your case would be something like this:

```
this.firestoreService.colWithIds$('users').pipe(
 switchMap((users: any[]) => { 
   const us = users.map((r: any) => { 
     return this.firestoreService
       .col$(`users/${r.id}/recipes`)
       .pipe(
         map(recipes => Object.assign(user, {recipes}))
       ); 
     }); 
   return combineLatest(...us); 
 })
).subscribe(users => console.log(users);
```

**While I have not tested this code**, I believe it's a good starting point for you, since this code  is getting the `users` values mapped to it’s sub-collection observables. Those `Recipes` values however are mapped back to the `user` values, with the sub-collection `Recipes` data containing as a new property.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Hi @RudyF please, consider upvoting or accepting this answer, in case it helped you in anyway, to solve your problem.